# Android App crashing on new intent(no error given)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a program that brings me to the activity *notes* through a button press. However, after adding the function to save and load, the app continuously crashes upon the loading of the activity. The **logcat** does not display any errors and the program is not reaching Notes activity.

***Button Code:***

```
Button NotesBtn = findViewById(R.id.NotesBtn);

NotesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent goToNotes = new Intent(Home.this,Notes.class);
        startActivity(goToNotes);
    }
});
```

Comment: paste the logcat error or warning too

Comment: is your android studio crashing or your app ?

Comment: did you add your activity to the manifest?

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm not working on this program anymore though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 Intent goToNotes = new Intent(Home.this,Notes.class.java);
        startActivity(goToNotes);
```

Comment: This is java snippet, so `Notes.class` is enough.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it